# Representing a polynom with a base

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How to do I present $$P(x)= 6x^2+4x+2$$ with the base $$B=\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\qquad x\sqrt\frac32,\qquad \sqrt\frac58(1-3x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_c=(1,X,X^2)$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb R_2[X]$. In this basis the coordinate vector $P=(2,4,6)^t$. Now the change matrix from $B_c$ to $B$ is 
$$Q=\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {2}}&0&\dfrac{\sqrt {5}}{\sqrt {8}}\\0&\dfrac{\sqrt {3}}{\sqrt {2}}&0\\1&0&-3\dfrac{\sqrt {5}}{\sqrt {8}}\end{pmatrix}$$ We compute the  matrix $Q^{-1}$ and 
 the coordinate vector of the polynomial $P$ in the basis 
$B$ is  obtained by taking the product $Q^{-1}P$ which gives the vector

$$(\dfrac{-8}{2 \sqrt5 + 3 \sqrt{10}}, \dfrac{-16}{2 \sqrt5 + 3 \sqrt{10}}, \dfrac{-24}{2 \sqrt5 + 3 \sqrt{10}})^t$$

meaning that 
$$P=\dfrac{-8}{2 \sqrt5 + 3 \sqrt{10}}*\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2} + \dfrac{-16}{2 \sqrt5 + 3 \sqrt{10}}*\dfrac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}x+ \dfrac{-24}{2 \sqrt5 + 3 \sqrt{10}}*\dfrac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt8}(1-3x^2)$$